# Getting argument type in a method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

I am trying to subclass a certain class and override some of its private methods. This is dangerous, could fail, could not pass Apple's review (In the AppStore), could have terrible effects, etc, but this is just for experimental/educational purposes :)

For example let's say I want to know the type of first argument of the instance method `keyboardInput:shouldInsertText:isMarkedText:` of `UITextView` :

```
SEL selector = @selector(keyboardInput:shouldInsertText:isMarkedText:);
Class class = [UITextView class];
Method method = class_getInstanceMethod(class, selector);
char *arg = method_copyArgumentType(method, 0);
printf("_%s_\n", arg);
free(arg);
```

However In the console I only get `_@_` . 
I think `@` means *object* but an object of what class? (I thought I would get the name of the class of the argument) Is it possible to get the class of that parameter using other [objective-c runtime functions](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html) or any other mean?

PS: In the example I used a class of Cocoa touch but I could have tried exactly the same with a class of Cocoa. So this should not be specific to iOS.

SOLVED:

I have tried in the simulator what Dave suggested, it worked!

`(gdb) info all-registers` gave me a long list of values,...

```
((gdb) po *(id*)($ebp + 8)
<MyTextView: 0x5911270; baseClass = UITextView; frame = (80 70; 240 323); text = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit er ...'; clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x5c0c7d0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>

(gdb) p *(SEL*)($ebp + 12)
$5 = (SEL) 0xbd19

(gdb) po *(id*)($ebp + 16)
<UIWebDocumentView: 0xa02f000; frame = (0 0; 240 457); text = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit er ...'; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <UIWebLayer: 0x5c35070>>

(gdb) po *(id*)($ebp + 20)
t

(gdb) p *(id*)($ebp + 24)
$6 = (id) 0x0
```

Which makes sense since the key I pressed was a single "t" so it was not marked text ("0x0") so I is OK to think that the first argument should be of type `UIWebDocumentView`.

Just one little thing (irrelevant in this case), how could I get the method name from a SEL in gbd? for example `$5` ?

Comment: The `SEL` *is* the method name. Use the `sel_getName` function to get the selector as a C string; see also http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/ . There's also `NSStringFromSelector`, which does exactly what it says, and is part of (and documented in) Foundation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming this is for academic interests *only*....

One way you could find out is to break on the symbol in GDB and inspect the parameters.  You know what *general* kind they are (ie, `float` vs `object`, etc), so you can simply use the right `p` command to print them.

To set the breakpoint, you can either do:

1. In the gdb console, type `b -[UITextView keyboardInput:shouldInsertText:isMarkedText:]`
2. In Xcode, add a new symbolic breakpoint for `-[UITextView keyboardInput:shouldInsertText:isMarkedText:]`

When you actually hit the breakpoint, you're not going to see anything useful (of course).  But you *can* print the arguments out at this point, because you know their sizes, and thus where they should be in the registers.

For more info on which registers they're in, check out [this handy blog post](http://www.clarkcox.com/blog/2009/02/04/inspecting-obj-c-parameters-in-gdb/).  You can also do something like `info all-registers` to print out all the information in all the registers, etc.

---

**update**

If you want to print the name of the selector, you can use a little trick, which is that selectors are more-or-less* `char*`s:

```
p (char*)$5
```

Will print:

```
${some number} = 0x{some address} "keyboardInput:shouldInsertText:isMarkedText:"
```

Comment: Thanks, It worked! I have one last and little doubt, though :) (Please read the updated answer)

Comment: +1 This is a simpler approach than my swizzling recommendation. I have a ready bookmark to that Clarkcox blog post myself. I reference it all the time.

Answer (score 9):

You cannot tell the class of the argument from introspection of the interface. All `id` are created equal in Objective-C, once you've been compiled. You can, however, ask a specific instance its `-class`. So if you're trying to reverse engineer an internal method, you'd need to swizzle the method, get it to be called, and then introspect the objects you're passed. Google "method swizzling" for plenty of discussion of how to inject your code into any Objective-C method.

Comment: I thought of swizzling, but In this case if I don't know the type of the first argument swizzling implementations won't work, I believe.

Comment: You know that it's an `id`. That's all you need. Remember, all `id` are created equal after compilation. That said, I do like @Dave DeLong's solution better for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

@ indeed means "object" but you can't find out of what class it is. This is not saved in the __OBJC segment of the binary and thus not available to you unless you have the original header file.

You have to guess it. :)